# XML output from HTTP request from Terminal

Tags: command-line, curl, https, xml

I am sending an `HTTP` request using `curl` from Terminal and would like to see or save the output (which by default comes in `xml`).

Here is the code I am using:

```
curl https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products?$search="name:S1A_IW_OCN__2SDV_20170904T063918_20170904T063943_018222_01EA1A_8E10.zip"
```

The output contains a lot of (what seems to me) random text (See image1)

If I run the same `http` request on the browser (see image 2), I do get the output in xml (I need the xml to extract once of the contained parameters)

[image: curl][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy curl command from developers tools:

[image: pic more details]

Check it:

```bsh
curl 'https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products?$search=%22name:S1A_IW_OCN__2SDV_20170904T063918_20170904T063943_018222_01EA1A_8E10.zip%22' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9' -H 'Cookie: SRVNAME=N02' --compressed
```

You can remove unnecessary headers as long as it works:

```bsh
curl 'https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products?$search=%22name:S1A_IW_OCN__2SDV_20170904T063918_20170904T063943_018222_01EA1A_8E10.zip%22' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'
```

Or short version (add `-H 'Accept: application/xml` only):

```bsh
curl 'https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products?$search=%22name:S1A_IW_OCN__2SDV_20170904T063918_20170904T063943_018222_01EA1A_8E10.zip%22' -H 'Accept: application/xml'
```